# JQuery displaying previous message on button click

Tags: jquery

I have tried to write some jQuery where once the button has been clicked it polls the server and once the action is complete it displays the message on the webpage.

This part works as expected, once the button is clicked, the spinner appears and the poll displays showing the number of emails sent. Once all the emails have been sent, it displays the correct message showing how many emails where sent and if any how many failed to sent.

Problem is, if I then click the button again, the previous message appears even though the polling is now running and does not disappear, the spinner does not appear either.

Can anyone help fix this problem

> because I do not know why its happening

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#spinner").hide();
    function doPoll() {
        $("#progressSend").html("");
        $("#progressSend").empty();
        $("#spinner").show();
        $.post("/pathtopolling", function (data) {
            if (data.startsWith("Completed")) {
                $("#progressSend").html("");
                $("#progressSend").html("<p class=\"text-info\">" + data + "1</p>");
                $("#spinner").hide();
                clearTimeout(doPoll);
            }
            else if (data.startsWith("Unable")) {
                $("#progressSend").html("");
                $("#progressSend").html("<p class=\"text-info\">" + data + "2</p>");
                $("#spinner").hide();
                clearTimeout(doPoll);
            }
            else {
                $("#progressSend").html("");
                $("#progressSend").html("<p class=\"text-info\">" + data + "3</p>");
                setTimeout(doPoll, 500);
            }

        });

    }
    var form = $("#frmSendMailingList");
    $(form).on("click", function (event) {
        $("#spinner").show();
        $("#progressSend").html("");
        $("#progressSend").empty();
        doPoll();
        event.preventDefault();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(form).attr("action"),
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            processData: false,
            success: function(result) {
                $("#spinner").hide();
                $("#progressSend").html("<p class=\"text-info\">" + result + "4</p>");
                clearTimeout(doPoll);
            },
            error: function(err) {
                $("#spinner").hide();
                clearTimeout(doPoll);
            }
        });
    });

            $("#btnMailingListReset").click(function () {
                location.reload(true);
                clearTimeout(doPoll);
            });
}).
```

Comment: Why have you added click functionality over the whole form $(form).on("click", function (event) {}. Try to refactor it into a button and then see the difference.

Comment: Hey, why do you put a click `event` on the form ?

Comment: @Sahil Sharma I had tried that, had the same problem previous message appears

Comment: The click event on the form is because putting it on the button never worked, it just displayed the previous message. Added to form to see if that made any difference and still does not work correctly

Comment: I have added an answer. Maybe it can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like @SahilSharma you should to attach this event on a `button`. However your issue it's normal because each time you're clicking the callback is fired too.

You have to declare a boolean, false at the begining, if a click is fired and this boolean is false : set it to true. And set it back to false when ajax is finish.

```
// the boolean
var clicked = false;

$('#btnSendMailingList').on("click", function (event) {
  if(!clicked){
    clicked = true;
    $("#spinner").show();
    $("#progressSend").html("");
    $("#progressSend").empty();
    doPoll();
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $(form).attr("action"),
        data: $(form).serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        processData: false,
        success: function(result) {
            $("#spinner").hide();
            $("#progressSend").html("<p class=\"text-info\">" + result + "4</p>");
            clearTimeout(doPoll);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            $("#spinner").hide();
            clearTimeout(doPoll);
        },
        complete: function(){
          clicked = false;
        }
     }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks GameTag, seems the clicked bool fixed the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate the click event from Form. Create a submit button in HTML and modify jQuery code like this:

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" value="Submit Form" id="btnSendMailingList"/>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#spinner").hide();
    function doPoll() {
        $("#progressSend").html("");
        $("#progressSend").empty();
        $("#spinner").show();
        $.post("/pathtopolling", function (data) {
            if (data.startsWith("Completed")) {
                $("#progressSend").html("");
                $("#progressSend").html("<p class=\"text-info\">" + data + "1</p>");
                $("#spinner").hide();
                clearTimeout(doPoll);
            }
            else if (data.startsWith("Unable")) {
                $("#progressSend").html("");
                $("#progressSend").html("<p class=\"text-info\">" + data + "2</p>");
                $("#spinner").hide();
                clearTimeout(doPoll);
            }
            else {
                $("#progressSend").html("");
                $("#progressSend").html("<p class=\"text-info\">" + data + "3</p>");
                setTimeout(doPoll, 500);
            }

        });

    }
    //var form = $("#frmSendMailingList"); Commented for fixation

    $('btnSendMailingList').on("click", function (event) {
        $("#spinner").show();
        $("#progressSend").html("");
        $("#progressSend").empty();
        doPoll();
        event.preventDefault();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(form).attr("action"),
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            processData: false,
            success: function(result) {
                $("#spinner").hide();
                $("#progressSend").html("<p class=\"text-info\">" + result + "4</p>");
                clearTimeout(doPoll);
            },
            error: function(err) {
                $("#spinner").hide();
                clearTimeout(doPoll);
            }
        });
    });

            $("#btnMailingListReset").click(function () {
                location.reload(true);
                clearTimeout(doPoll);
            });
}).
```